# Why Simple axios is not working on React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, graphql, axios

I am trying to fetch data using axios on React Native, Expo android client. I wrote:

```
axios({
    url: 'http://my_local_id/graphql',
    method: 'get',
    data: {
      query: `
      query allPosts {
        posts(listType: "all") {
          text
        }
       }
      `,
    }
  }).then(result => {
    console.log(result.data);
  }).catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
    console.log(error.request._response);
  });
```

The error gives me a log: "Request failed with status code 400" and some additional messages

Stack trace:   node_modules\axios\lib\core\createError.js:16:24 in createError   node_modules\axios\lib\core\settle.js:19:6 in settle   node_modules\axios\lib\adapters\xhr.js:77:13 in handleLoad   node_modules\event-target-shim\lib\event-target.js:172:43 in dispatchEvent   node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Network\XMLHttpRequest.js:570:23 in setReadyState   node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Network\XMLHttpRequest.js:392:25 in __didCompleteResponse   node_modules\react-native\Libraries\vendor\emitter\EventEmitter.js:191:12 in emit   node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:349:47 in __callFunction   node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:106:26 in    node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:297:10 in __guard   node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:105:17 in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue   [native code]:null in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue

I looked at the message from error.request._response and it reads that  "message":"POST body sent invalid JSON."
But I only sent a "get" request. I have no idea what is wrong here. Below is my package.json file.

```
"axios": "^0.18.0",
 "expo": "^32.0.0",
 "react": "16.5.0",
"react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-32.0.0.tar.gz",
```

Comment: Why did you send a `GET` request with `data` attribute? In a `GET` request, the `data` attribute is supposed to be `undefined`.

Comment: @CùĐứcHiếu Because I am requesting a query, not a mutation. How should I properly request a query then? Should I use a POST method? This article uses POST for a query. https://medium.com/@stubailo/how-to-call-a-graphql-server-with-axios-337a94ad6cf9

Comment: Uhmm do you know that graphql only accepts GET method with parameter `query` in query string? https://graphql.org/learn/serving-over-http/#get-request. And axios does not accept parameters for GET method in `data`, but in `params`: https://github.com/axios/axios#example. You might need to test your query somewhere first, e.g. Postman to check its validity.

Comment: I do not work with `graphql` so I cannot assist you with that. As for `Axios`, if you need the `data` attribute, consider using `POST`. Based on what you wrote in your question, I believe that when the `data` attribute is specified, the `method` attribute is always `POST` regardless of what you put there. If you need to use `GET`, consider using `queryString` instead of the `data` attribute.

Comment: @CùĐứcHiếu It is resolved! Thank you very much for pointing out that I was using "data" for a "get "method"!

Comment: @blaz I found that many examples on the web actually use "post" method for sending a query. But I also tried "params" as you suggested and it worked too! Thank you!